# Шорткод не работает при обновлении страницы через ajax

Tags: wordpress, ajax, woocommerce, shortcode

Интернет-магазин на WooCommerce.

На странице листинга товаров для каждого товара выводятся кнопки "добавить в избранное" и "добавить в сравнение" через шорткоды соответствующих плагинов "YITH add to wishlist" и "YITH compare":

```
[yith_wcwl_add_to_wishlist]
[yith_compare_button]
```

Также на странице присутствуют фильтры по атрибутам товаров, которые работают на Ajax — отмечаешь чек-бокс, листинг товаров перегружается с применением этого фильтра.

Проблема: при нажатии на один из фильтров, в карточках товаров срабатывает только один шорткод [yith_wcwl_add_to_wishlist], а второй выводится в виде текста: "[yith_compare_button]". Проблема именно в этом шорткоде, очередность выводов шорткодов ситуацию не исправляет.

Почему такое может быть и куда рыть чтобы это починить?

Если это возможно, то в идеале починить не меняя код плагинов и темы — хочется сохранить возможность обновлять сайт в будущем.

Comment: Похоже, что ajax написан неправильно, поэтому плагины не инициализируются. Должно быть так https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html

Comment: Нет, в том-то и дело, что инициируется только один плагин. А второй - в виде текста шорткода отображается.

Comment: Вот в том-то и дело, что один. Покажите, как вы делаете ajax.

Comment: Задача все еще актуальна. 

Я использую готовую тему Impreza, в которой есть готовый функционал фильтров для каталога товаров. Как посмотреть "как я делаю ajax"? Мне надо код всей темы разбирать, а это слишком сложная для меня задача.